# 1960s (?) novel about alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

It starts with a man, his wife, his son and his son's girlfriend in bunker. The wife and son defect to the aliens, the man ends up with his son's girlfriend, and fights the aliens.

Comment: We really need more details. Were the aliens humanoids? Tentacle abominations? Floating frisbees? Do you remember anything about the cover or the writing style of the book? Did the man fight with guns? Swords? Ray guns? Psychic powers? Magic? Take a look at [these questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see how many of them you can answer and edit said answers into your question.

Comment: Strangely, I THINK you may be mis-remembering details of [Farnham's Freehold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farnham%27s_Freehold).  It's missing the daughter (and Hugh ends up with his daughter's friend, not his son's) and Joseph, their housekeeper, and they aren't aliens, but simply the people of the future.. But if it was read a long time ago, I could still see it fit.  Did you read it that long ago?

Comment: @K-H-W that was my first thought as well. Probably worth developing into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's [*Farnham's Freehold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farnham's_Freehold) (1964) by Heinlein, then the "aliens" are simply black persons who have somehow taken over the post-apocalyptic world. The surviving white Americans are slaves. The housekeeper is accepted into the "Chosen" because he is black, but the son ends up being castrated. When they get an opportunity to return to their own time, he refuses to go with them in his present condition. So both he and the housekeeper may be said to have defected.

> It is revealed toward the end that the Chosen are cannibals, which ruffled a few feathers and led to mutterings about "racism" from the politically correct.

Comment: Can you confirm the details from the question match Farnharm's Freehold? Otherwise, this is more of a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: They match as far as they go. FF starts with the family in a fallout shelter as WW3 breaks out, and a nuclear blast catapults them into the future. As noted above both the son and the housekeeper "defect" for different reasons.